# How to use dictionary to replace first to characters of a string?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a webscraper that inputs values into a data extractor. The dates have to be accepted a one month back.
For example January is equal to 00.

'''

```
    today="02-10-2020"
    preDay="02-09-2020"
    months ={"01":"00","02":"01","03":"02","04":"03","05":"04","06":"05",
           "07":"06","08":"07","09":"08","10":"09","11":"10","12":"11"}
    for cur, pre in months.items():
        today= today[0:2].replace(cur, pre)
```

'''
Maybe I do not complete understand how dictionaries are iterated but when I try doing this. I will replace all the values that match the key. I only want to it change the first two characters in the string and then leave the rest of the data alone.
I have successfully done the action with an "if" statement but I would to try the same using a dictionary.

Comment: Why don't you try going step by step and first learning what `today[0:2]`, then learning what happens to a string when you do `a_string.replace(cur, pre)`? Then you can figure out how to use what.

Comment: Dictionaries can be used to replace a one thing with another. Imagine it being a bit like list that you can reference instead of with a number but with the key you have chosen. Such as in your months dictionary "01". This means doing months["01"] will return "00". See if you can get your code working now. If not feel free to ask more question

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly there is no need for a loop at all.
To convert the month part of the date back one month using your dictionary you could simply.

```
today="02-10-2020"
months ={"01":"00","02":"01","03":"02","04":"03","05":"04","06":"05",
        "07":"06","08":"07","09":"08","10":"09","11":"10","12":"11"}

today = today.replace(today[0:2], months[today[0:2]], 1)
print(today)

#output:
#01-10-2020
```

According to the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

str.replace(old, new[, count])

Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

So the code I wrote takes the first two characters as the old and replaces it with the value from the dictionary at the key that matches the first two characters. The "1" at the end makes sure this replacement only happens once.

Comment: Thank you, this makes much more sense now. All apologies.